# Why when multiplying a DECIMAL field is the answer rounded up?

Tags: mysql

I have a **DECIMAL(18,3)** field that I multiply with 12, using a trigger. Using any calculator would return for example 644.8 * 12 = 7737.6. but MySQL returns 7738. What gives?
Trigger:

`SET NEW.Perannum = NEW.Wage * 12;`

Comment: Show us the code you use to multiply.

Comment: Hm, perhaps something else is going on. I get 7737.6 here: http://sqlize.com/b093D2laUj

Comment: What is the datatype of NEW.Perannum? Seems to be INT or non-float

Comment: Please note that the above trigger snippet is the only part where the field Perannum is actually used. Perannum is DECIMAL(18,3), so is Wage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try multiplying by 12.00 to ensure a decimal value * a decimal value...

Comment: +! there's also good documentation on mysql's handling of precision... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-examples.html, etc.

Comment: That did it. I love Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the math of it. "Rounding" always means to go to the nearest decimal point in the next place -- up or down.
For instance, if your results need precision of 0 decimal points and your calculations are .5 or less, it will round down.  If the calculations are greater than .5, it will round up.
What you are looking for is "Truncating", which means "throw the extra remainder away".